# cocoa memory leak by CGAffineTranform or by view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

As instrument tell me, I have a leak in the code.
I dont quite get it at all.

my code is like this,

```
CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0,20.0);   
[[appDelegate.editController view] setTransform:myTrnsform];
appDelegate.editController.imageView.image=image;
[[sharedPicker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[appDelegate.window bringSubviewToFront:appDelegate.editController.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[sharedPicker release];
```

But instrument tell me the line

`[[appDelegate.editController view] setTransform:myTrnsform];`

is leaking memory.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need more code in order to answer it properly, but the line that makes me smell a memory leak is this one:

```
appDelegate.editController.imageView.image=image;
```

I'm not sure where are you getting the variable `image`, but when you assign it to the `image` property of `imageView` it will be retained, and you need to balance that call (either with a `release` or an `autorelease` at some point).

Comment: thanks! pgb! I added [image release]; and no longer with that leaking :) Thank you very much!